# Set own year and month when read date column from excel to r

Tags: r, excel, date, readxl

I read excel (xlsx) file to r with readxl package.

There are columns with date (hour:minute) type in excel and it's read in R in year:month:day:hour:minute:seconds format. Issue is R paste *1899-12-31* in front of time and convert to Posixct format.

I want to paste *year-month-day* that I want, for example to paste *2020-12-13* in front of time.

Are there any  options? Any help is welcome!

*I can calculate difference in time and add to get necessary year, month and day but I want more stable option*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Jakub.Novotny, I solved the issue

in workload dataset timeTotalH is Posixct with 1899-12-31 and I needed 2020-07-01

```
library(data.table)
library(stringr)
workload[,timeTotalH][1]
[1] 1899-12-31 12:25:00
workload1[,str_replace(timeTotalH,"1899-12-31", "2020-07-01")]
[1] "2020-07-01 12:25:00 +06"
str(workload1[,str_replace(timeTotalH,"1899-12-31", "2020-07-01")])
POSIXct[1:1], format: "2020-07-01 12:25:00"
```

I got what I needed

Answer (score 1):

Read it in as character, substitute "1899-" with "2020-" and parse the date later on.